# Default undoManager is nil when testing

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, nsundomanager

I am working on adding some tests to a Swift library which uses `undoManager`. In the library's demo, adding the following print to `viewDidAppear:` results in an `NSUndoManagerObject` being printed.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    print(undoManager)
}
```

I wrote another ViewController for the tests, and when I have the same code in the ViewController's `viewDidAppear:`, `nil` is printed.

I'm creating the ViewController for the tests with the following code:

```
override func setUp() {
    super.setUp()

    // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType))

    viewController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as! ViewController
    viewController.viewDidLoad()
    viewController.viewDidAppear(false)

    // Test and Load the View at the Same Time!
    XCTAssertNotNil(viewController.view)
}
```

I call `becomeFirstResponder()` inside of the ViewController's `viewDidLoad:`.

I want to test logic that uses the default `undoManager`, so I need to figure out why it's `nil`. I've tried assigning the default `undoManager` a new instance of `NSUndoManager`, but it's a read only property.

Here is the [Github repository](https://github.com/dehli/TouchDraw/tree/a2903aa2e28b1f6724ba33671ee1023309e6fdf6) if you're interested in seeing the code.

Comment: Call `loadView` just before `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: @nhgrif Just tried that with no luck :( Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to get the default `undoManager` working with testing for this project, but I ended up using the following solution which I think works just as well. In the class that uses the `undoManager`, I've added a private `NSUndoManager` variable and then defined it inside of `init` like so:

```
classUndoManager = undoManager
if classUndoManager == nil {
    classUndoManager = NSUndoManager()
}
```

Anywhere that used `undoManager` now uses `classUndoManager`.